# Merge migration, data-migration

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, retag-request

They're being used as synonyms.

[migration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration)

[data-migration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-migration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. is there a way to complete a merge request without answering it or closing it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I did add the "status-completed" tag to indicate that this was done.

Comment: Yeah, but I got a "tumbleweed" badge for asking a question that not one person tried to answer. So Stack Exchange thinks this was just flapping in the wind, when in fact it was completed.